# How do I dynamically resize a textarea using hitches in Nametag.js

Tags: jquery, textarea

In my Nametag.js widget I want a `<textarea>` to resize dynamically when the container view changes size.  Normally I'd do this by promoting it to a nametag, with `class="nametag"`, and using a hitch like `width:"%%{self.parent.height;;value}"`.

What I WANT to do is something like this

```
<textarea class="nametag" height="%{self.parent.height;;value-20}" width="%{self.parent.width;;value}">       
    Some default text here...
```

But that doesn't work.

I know I can use the `self` CSS trait to get a reference to self on the textarea, can I use that to somehow enable a hitch to change its size to follow the size of the container?

Answer (score 0):

Hitches work on any tag that can be a "nametag", like `<div>`, `<span>`, `<fieldset>` etc. A few HTML-tags, such as `<textarea>`, `<input>`, and `<pre>` don't support DOM content (i.e. text-only), and are incompatible with object-oriented templating.

Instead, use a parent view's hitch, resizing the textarea whenever the view itself changes.

Here's how i'd write it:

```
<view height="%%{self.parent.height}" 
      width="%%{self.parent.width}"
      onSizeChanged="%%{self.width, self.height;;$(self.firstChild).width(self.width).height(self.height)}">       
    <textarea name="content">Some default text here...</textarea>
</view>
```

This uses the hitch syntax to specify that when either the width or height changes of the view (self) changes, set the first child (the textarea) to the dimensions of the view. The view is listening to it's parent's width and height too, so that as the container is expanded, the textarea is resized.